# How do I write if a variable has a classList of "x" listen for an event, otherwise don't listen for the event until the variable has the classList "x"

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a dropdown hamburger menu for my fixed navbar. I want the menu to open and close when clicking the hamburger icon. I also want the menu to close if it's open and there is a window scroll event.

It seems to be working fine if I'm at the top of my page. However, once the page has been scrolled down a bit, the menu will not open and to open it up again I would have to scroll up to the top of the page and click on the hamburger icon. This defeats the purpose of the navbar.

I think the problem in my code is that once the scroll event listener has been triggered once, it keeps on listening for a scroll event regardless of whether navBtn contains "nav-open". What I want it to do is to only listen for a scroll event if navBtn has the "nav-open" class and then if I scroll, remove the "nav-open" class and stop listening for a scroll event until I click on the hamburger menu again thus toggling the "nav-open" class for navBtn.

Thanks in advance

Here is the code:

```
const select = selector => document.querySelector(selector);

const navBtn = select('.mobile-navbar__btn');
const navOpen = select('.mobile-navbar__open');

// Toggling the hamburger menu
function toggle() {
    navBtn.classList.toggle('nav-open');
    navOpen.classList.toggle('nav-open');
} 

// Open and close the hamburger menu
navBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    toggle();

    if(navBtn.classList.contains('nav-open')) {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
            console.log('scroll');
            navBtn.classList.remove('nav-open');
            navOpen.classList.remove('nav-open');
        });
    } else {
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: well your code will add multiple scroll event listeners so that is not a good thing.

Comment: @epascarello could you let me know how I would go about changing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the event that you add.

```
const scrollFunction = () => {
  navBtn.classList.remove('nav-open');
  navOpen.classList.remove('nav-open');
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollFunction);
}

// Open and close the hamburger menu
navBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  toggle();

  if (navBtn.classList.contains('nav-open')) {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollFunction);
  } else {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollFunction);
  }
});
```